# compilation error, uninitialized value '__pure'

Tags: c, compiler-errors, compilation

I am trying to compile my code using the new version of the arm-none-eabi compiler (10.3) and I am having errors. The compiler points to its strings file.h and gives the following errors

```
error: expected initializer before '__pure'
error: expected initializer before '__pure2'
```

What does this mean and why doesn't he know it? Do I have to define them myself?

Something similar is written inside the strings.h file

```
#include <sys/cdefs.h>
#include <sys/_types.h>

#if __POSIX_VISIBLE >= 200809
#include <sys/_locale.h>
#endif

#ifndef _SIZE_T_DECLARED
typedef __size_t    size_t;
#define _SIZE_T_DECLARED
#endif

__BEGIN_DECLS
#if __BSD_VISIBLE || __POSIX_VISIBLE <= 200112
int  bcmp(const void *, const void *, size_t) __pure;   /* LEGACY */
void     bcopy(const void *, void *, size_t);           /* LEGACY */
void     bzero(void *, size_t);                 /* LEGACY */
#endif
#if __BSD_VISIBLE
void     explicit_bzero(void *, size_t);
#endif
#if __MISC_VISIBLE || __POSIX_VISIBLE < 200809 || __XSI_VISIBLE >= 700
int  ffs(int) __pure2;
#endif
#if __BSD_VISIBLE
int  ffsl(long) __pure2;
int  ffsll(long long) __pure2;
int  fls(int) __pure2;
int  flsl(long) __pure2;
int  flsll(long long) __pure2;
#endif
#if __BSD_VISIBLE || __POSIX_VISIBLE <= 200112
char    *index(const char *, int) __pure;           /* LEGACY */
char    *rindex(const char *, int) __pure;          /* LEGACY */
#endif
int  strcasecmp(const char *, const char *) __pure;
int  strncasecmp(const char *, const char *, size_t) __pure;

#if __POSIX_VISIBLE >= 200809
int  strcasecmp_l (const char *, const char *, locale_t);
int  strncasecmp_l (const char *, const char *, size_t, locale_t);
#endif
__END_DECLS

#if __SSP_FORTIFY_LEVEL > 0
#include <ssp/strings.h>
#endif

#endif /* _STRINGS_H_ */
```

Comment: The message in your title is different from the message in your question.

Comment: Are you using some third-party libraries (meaning _anything_ except standard C or C++ headers)? For example, Xilinx driver libraries have a define for `str` which makes the `str()` from `std::stringstream` output all sorts of unintelligible errors.

Comment: @PhilMasteG `std::stringstream` in C language will lead to errors :)

Comment: @0___________ I did not say to use `std::stringstream` in C, of course this will not work. However, I often have to include the Xilinx headers in C++ code, where std::stringstream would work but std::stringstream::str() will give compile errors due to the defined `str` as an inline assembly macro. It was an example of weird behaviours due to defines, accompanied by the limited supply of abbreviations. ;)

Comment: Try to compile with `-ffreestanding`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You miss definition of `__pure`.

I guess that is related to `__attribute__((pure))` which defines a `pure` function.

As a workaround, I would suggest

```
#define __pure
```

as it only affects possible optimisations.

Pure function:

> Calls to functions that have no observable effects on the state of the
> program other than to return a value may lend themselves to
> optimizations such as common subexpression elimination. Declaring such
> functions with the pure attribute allows GCC to avoid emitting some
> calls in repeated invocations of the function with the same argument
> values.
>
> The pure attribute prohibits a function from modifying the state of
> the program that is observable by means other than inspecting the
> function’s return value. However, functions declared with the pure
> attribute can safely read any non-volatile objects, and modify the
> value of objects in a way that does not affect their return value or
> the observable state of the program.
>
> For example,
>
> ```
> int hash (char *) __attribute__ ((pure));
> ```
>
> tells GCC that subsequent calls to the function hash with the same
> string can be replaced by the result of the first call provided the
> state of the program observable by hash, including the contents of the
> array itself, does not change in between. Even though hash takes a
> non-const pointer argument it must not modify the array it points to,
> or any other object whose value the rest of the program may depend on.
> However, the caller may safely change the contents of the array
> between successive calls to the function (doing so disables the
> optimization). The restriction also applies to member objects
> referenced by the this pointer in C++ non-static member functions.
>
> Some common examples of pure functions are strlen or memcmp.
> Interesting non-pure functions are functions with infinite loops or
> those depending on volatile memory or other system resource, that may
> change between consecutive calls (such as the standard C feof function
> in a multithreading environment).
>
> The pure attribute imposes similar but looser restrictions on a
> function’s definition than the const attribute: pure allows the
> function to read any non-volatile memory, even if it changes in
> between successive invocations of the function. Declaring the same
> function with both the pure and the const attribute is diagnosed.
> Because a pure function cannot have any observable side effects it
> does not make sense for such a function to return void. Declaring such
> a function is diagnosed.

Comment: any comment silent DVter?